# "Tuvo" vs "tenía"

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

What is the difference between 'tuvo' and 'tenía'? Por ejemplo, "Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque tuvo que comprar leche." vs "Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque tenía que comprar leche." Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct (although, if you are using *Pretérito perfecto* for `ir`, why wouldn't you use te same for `tener`?).

> Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque **tuvo** que comprar leche. (Pretérito perfecto simple)
>
> Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque **tenía** que comprar leche (Pretérito imperfecto)

The difference between both verb tenses is that  *Pretérito perfecto simple* (and all verb tenses with a *perfecto* grammatical aspect) are used for well delimited actions (definite beginning and definite end, even if beginning or end are not clearly stated) finished in the past and the *Pretérito imperfecto* (and other verb tenses with the *imperfecto* grammatical aspect) emphasize the continuity of an action (or the action did not have a definite beginning or a definite end).

You could see more clearly a difference this way:

> Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque **esa tarde** *tuvo* que comprar leche.

This express a well defined action in the past. Just that evening she had to buy more milk.

> Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque **cada tarde** tenía que comprar leche.

For this last one "iba" could work better if you want to express a repeated action (every evening she used to go to the store, because every evening she had to buy milk). Both verb tenses would be in concordance. But you could also say

> Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque **esa tarde** tenía que comprar leche **para hacer una tarta**.

This later example expresses an action that involves some continuity and without  well definite beginning or end (buying milk in order to bake a cake).

Comment: Bear in mind: "My mother went to the store because she used to have to buy milk to make x's."  That would be the English for cada tarde and tenía que comprar leche, which the OP may not know. I understand you are explaining the Spanish, but I thought it would be useful to explain the English.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me suena mejor 'tenia.' Tuvo es una accion del pasado y no suena bien en esta oracion. Contensta a la pregunta: Por que fue tu Mama a la tienda?

Comment: `Tenía` es también una acción del pasado. A mi ambas me suenan bien. La diferencia entre usar un tiempo verbal u otro está en la duración de la acción.

Answer (score 0):

No suena bien la primera opción "Mi mamá fue a la tienda porque tuvo que comprar leche".
Tal vez sea mas por el significado que por la gramática.
Parecería que un pasado "fue" es anterior al otro "tuvo"... Lo que no parece correcto, visto el significado de la frase.
La necesidad estaba antes de la acción. Fué porque tenía.
Si en lugar de "porque", fuese "y":
"Mi mamá fue a la tienda y tuvo que comprar leche (una vez allí surgió algo por lo que tuvo que comprar la leche)"